# Whole tables in memory and commit very couple of hours

Tags: sql-server, database, caching, optimization, sql-server-2019

I have a crawler program running on a Windows 2019 VPS and the main bottleneck of the program is database operations. I tried to use the fastest hardware - SSD NVME, Core i9 CPU and 16GB DDR4 RAM and as much as I've tried to optimize it, it still needs to do a lot of inserts, updates and selects. So I was wondering if I could make the database to load every table in memory and every couple of hours just commit the data to the disk.

Comment: Do you even have enough RAM to theoretically store all tables in it? 16 GB isn't that much...

Comment: And you might first check what is the bottleneck in detail. Reading data? Because of disk I/O or because of poorly indexed data? Writing data? ...

Comment: @stickybit so far the database is rather small but there are lots of operation and I want maximum speed. And the bottoleneck is a combination of all of the things you mentioned. If it was only reading data, I'd leave it to SQL Server's caching but at the same time there are many inserts too

Comment: @stickybit so far the database is rather small but there are lots of operation and I want maximum speed. And the bottoleneck is a combination of all of the things you mentioned. If it was only reading data, I'd leave it to SQL Server's caching but at the same time there are many inserts too

Comment: if your crud rate is very very high you can use in-memory-OLTP technology in sql server. with this technic you have a table on RAM and you havent the disck problem

Comment: @MahdiRahimi thanks. Is there an option to commit the database to disc every couple of hours with this technology?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori in sql server you have two type in-memory table. in first type you have table at memory only and in second type the in-memory table sync with storage and commit data async

Comment: but be carefull about use this technology first you should do every perforfmance tips like unit allocation size or stagedb and heap table and surely you will be monitor your sql server engine and solve lock & block &latch in your server